# Pieceworker and Landing Net

Tags: agricola

This came up in an online game I was playing yesterday and I wasn't confident in what would happen...

I have the Pieceworker Occupation:

*Whenever you receive wood, clay, reed, stone or grain on an action space, you can buy one more of the same good for 1 food...*

as well as the Landing Net Minor Improvement:

*Whenever you receive reed on an action space, you receive an additional 2 food...*

Suppose I have no food  in my supply and take the Reed action space. Can I use the additional 2 food gained with the Landing Net to buy an additional Reed with the Pieceworker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [compendium](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/34558/the-unofficial-agricola-compendium)

> The Pieceworker is used before other cards, so you cannot convert goods that your receive from an occupation or improvement

Comment: Surely you could have researched this on BGG the same as I...

Comment: that is an unofficial source, but I cannot seem to find this covered in an official FAQ.

Comment: It's *authoritative*, but... well, I tried.

Comment: The Compendium is an authoritative enough source for me (though not authoritative enough that people shouldn't be allowed to argue against its rulings, if they disagree with them!)

Comment: @thesunneversets - And did you try it online? What did it allow? It would be interesting to know what the online implementation chose here.

Comment: @The Chaz - Not sure what point you're trying to make here, although I've noticed you try to make it before. The existence of information on BGG has no bearing on whether or not this question should have been asked. Perhaps you have a specific concern about some questions being too trivial? If so, please bring it up on meta and we can discuss it.

Comment: @ire_and_curses - I'm afraid I lost my bottle and deliberately didn't use up my last food buying an extra Wood, so that I could definitely afford the extra Reed I needed to get with my next action.  Too late now I think, but I could ask the Boite a Jeux management perhaps.  Agree with you totally about BGG by the way - I think a policy of "check on BGG first and if you can't find the answer there, ask here" would be the last nail in BG:SE's coffin!

Comment: @ire: it must be my math.SE upbringing, wherein motivation/personal effort are encouraged. I'm drafting a meta question, but am realizing that I'm not exactly sure what the problem is. Did the OP research the answer? That would be nice to know in the body, and would have saved me 6-7 minutes (of my valuable time! *wink*). Are we expecting the developer to visit BG.SE and personally answer the question? I've seen such things on MO, but the sites and topics are quite different...

Comment: @user1873 The compendium is as official as you can get http://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/9879041#9879041